# MySQL query based on user input in c

Tags: mysql, c

how to take input from user in c and use this input in where clause of mysql statement

```
int main(){
    char *input;
    scanf("%s",input);
    mysql_quer(con,"select * from < tablename > where < column > = input ");
}
```

Comment: Look into `sprintf()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use c? If you used c++ you would have the std::string and could easily add the string together.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char *input;
> scanf("%s",input);
> ```

This is a problem. `input` is just a pointer to somewhere, it's not an actual buffer that can store input, and it's not automatically pointing anywhere meaningful.  You should set aside a buffer to store your input:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20 // or however big you need your buffer to be
...
char input[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) )
{
  /**
   * fgets doesn't strip the trailing newline
   */
  char *newline = strchr( input, '\n' );
  if ( newline )
    *newline = 0;

  // use input
}
else
{
  // error or EOF on input
}
```

`scanf` is *not* a great tool for interactive input, and the `%s` conversion specifier opens the same security hole that `gets` used to - if the user types in more characters than the buffer is sized to hold, then C will happily store those extra characters to the memory following the buffer, potentially clobbering something important.

If your heart is set on using `scanf`, then you need to provide an explicit maximum input size as part of the `%s` specifier, like `%20s`.  Unfortunately, such maximum input sizes must be hardcoded in the format; `scanf` doesn't have a way for you to provide it as an argument the way `printf` does.  You can use the following nonsense to work around it:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20
#define STR(x) #x
#define FMT(len) "%" STR(len) "s"
...
scanf( FMT(BUFFER_SIZE), input );
```

It's just easier to use `fgets` (and `fgets` allows for blank spaces in the input, whereas the `%s` conversion specifier will stop reading after the first whitespace character).  Tradeoff is that you have to handle the trailing newline.

> ```
> mysql_quer(con,"select * from  where  = input ");
> ```

You *never* want to pass user input directly to a SQL statement; see the parable of [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) for why.  You'll want to do some sanity checking on your inputs (make sure there are no `';'` or `'''` characters at least).  Although it's a bit of work, you'd probably want to use a prepared statement - [here's an example](http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/06/23/sentencias-preparadas-de-mysql-en-c-ejemplo-completo/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf()` to insert the input variable into the SQL string. And the value has to be in quotes if it's a string. Also, you never allocated space for `input`.

```
char input[BUFSIZ];
char sql[BUFSIZ];
scanf("%s", input);
sprintf(sql, "select * from tablename where column = '%s' ", input);
mysql_query(con, sql);
```